# Enumerative projective geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am wondering whether for any two lines $\mathfrak{L}, \mathfrak{L'}$ and any point $\mathfrak{P}$ in $\mathbf{P}^3$ there is a line having nonempty intersection with all of $\mathfrak{L}, \mathfrak{L'}$, $\mathfrak{P}$. I don't really know how to approach this, because I was never taught thinking about such a problem, not even related ones. I think the answer should be no, but have no means to justify it. Perhaps use the Klein representation of lines in 3 space? Could someone also recommend a book where similar problems are solved or at least posed as exercises? Also feel free to give an algebraic geometry perspective, but I don't really know how to approach this with algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Consider the plane spanned by $\mathfrak L$ and $\mathfrak P$.

A lovely elementary book is Pedoe's *Geometry: A Comprehensive Course*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true.

One way to see it is *projection away from $P$*: this is a rational map $
\mathbf P^3 \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^2$. Points in the target $\mathbf P^2$ correspond to lines in $\mathbf P^3$ passing through $P$. Now under this map, the two lines $L$ and $L'$ map to lines $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda'$ in $\mathbf P^2$. Since they are lines in the plane, they intersect in a point, and this point corresponds to the line in $\mathbf P^3$ you're looking for.

This is an elementary example of *Schubert calculus* on the Grassmannian $\mathbb G(1,3)$ of lines in $\mathbf P^3$. You can look at the book *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths--Harris for a thorough treatment, explaining how questions of this kind can be solved systematically.

Comment: Good answer!. Your name at this site means to our language differently. `Asal` means `Honey` in my culture. :-) +1

Comment: @BabakS. Thanks for the vote, and the interesting linguistic information!